# How can I access a char in string in at specific number?

Tags: string, kotlin, char, kotlin-android-extensions

I tried this code but it is giving me errors. So how can I access a character in a string in kotlin? In java, it can be done by the `charAt()` method.

```
private fun abc(x: String) {
    var i: Int = 0
    while (x[i].toString() != "+") {
        var y: Char = x[i]
        i++
    }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? maybe the error message is helping you.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The equivalent of Javas [String.charAt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) in Kotlin is [String.get()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/get.html). Since this is implemented as an operator, you can use `[index]` instead of `get(index)`. For example

```
val firstChar: Char = "foo"[0]
```

or if you prefer

```
val someString: String = "bar"
val firstChar: Char = someString.get(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this method instead?

```
private fun abc(x: String) {
    $p = 1; 
    do {
        $p++
    }while (x[p]!= "+")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of Kotlin is that you can do it in few ways, eg.

1. You can simply access it by index:

   ```
   while (x[i] != '+') {
       i++
   }
   ```
2. Converting to `CharArray`

   ```
   val chars: CharArray = x.toCharArray()

   while (chars[i] != '+') {
       i++
   }
   ```
3. You can also use idiomatic Kotlin (preferred):

   - **forEach**

     ```
     x.forEach { c ->
         if (c == '+') return@forEach
     }
     ```
   - **forEachIndexed** if you care about index

     ```
     x.forEachIndexed { index, c ->
         if (c == '+') {
             println("index=$index")
             return@forEachIndexed
         }
     }
     ```

In both cases, your character is accessed with `c`

Comment: thanks i liked it converting to charArray.