# Where is Kotlin string get index 0 or 1 based, implementation or target defined documented?

Tags: kotlin

I do  not see where [kotlin-stdlib/kotlin/String/get](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/get.html#kotlin.String) indicates whether it is 0 or 1 based, target or implementation defined. Where is this documented?

Comment: get() on a String is 0 indexed as this answer shows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50298227/7902532

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i access a char in string in at specific number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297288/how-can-i-access-a-char-in-string-in-at-specific-number)

Comment: It's zero-based like any other collection/array structure

Answer (score 1):

It is 0-based.

For example:

```
val str = "Hello Kotlin Strings"
println(str.get(4)) //prints o
```